# How to undo "go mod init"

Tags: go

The version of Go I'm using is

```
go version
go version go1.15.6 darwin/amd64
```

I did `go mod init example.com/m` under my folder `/***.com/m/`
Now I would like to do `go mod init ***.com/m`, it shows as

```
go.mod already exists
```

How could I clean up the `go.mod` which is unwanted?

Comment: `go.mod` is a text file. Open it in a text editor and edit the first line which contains the import path of your module however you wish. Did you read up some introduction material on Go modules like [this one](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules)?

Comment: Alternatively, you may use the `go mod edit` command to do that, if you wish. In your case, you'd do `go mod edit -module ***.com/m`. You might want to read the output of running `go help mod edit`. And still, if you simply want to _replace_ the existing `go.mod` file, just physically delete it (using Finder or running `rm go.mod` in a shell) and then do `go mod init` again. There's no magic: `go.mod` is a single text file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `go mod init` command creates the file `go.mod`. Delete the file to undo the action. Use `del go.mod` on Windows and `rm go.mod` on other systems.